# Manage CompletionStage inside of Netty handler

Tags: java, promise, netty

How do I best handle exceptions when calling a service that returns a `CompletionStage` from inside a Netty handler.

The way I see it there are two types of exceptions that need to be handled:

1. Exceptions that occur when generating the `CompletionStage` inside of the called service
2. Exceptions that occur when evaluating the content of the returned `CompletionStage`

Is this sufficient to cover both scenarios:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
  try {
    myService.call(arg1).whenComplete((response, throwable) -> {
      if (throwable != null) {
        ctx.fireExceptionCaught(throwable);
      } else {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
      }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof DecoderException) {
      throw e;
    } else {
      throw new DecoderException(e.getCause());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what you have shown in your code should cover both correctly.